# Missing browse icon for app in Xcode 5

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

The browse file icon for navigating to an app's icon is missing in my XCode 5. The same applies to the launch image. Below is a screenshot:

[image: no icons for navigating to file locations]

How can I get the file navigation icons to appear?

Comment: well, did you add images of the proper dimensions to your resources folder ?

Comment: no, the default images still there